# How to show only the parent folder in the shell prompt

Tags: linux, shell

Whenever I go inside a directory in Linux, it shows the file path at prompt like:

```
root@vivek-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:/var/www/abc/def/
```

How can I change it to show short names instead?

Comment: Assuming you use bash, what's the value of your `PS1` variable? What would you like your prompt to be instead?

Comment: \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$

Comment: You can safely keep the old one and just change the `\w` to `\W` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` (whatever you have or want – [what is the difference?](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)):

```
PS1="\u@\h:\W $ "
```

This will produce:

```
werner@charon:Documents $ cd /etc/paths.d/
werner@charon:paths.d $
```

More infos: [How to: Change / Setup bash custom prompt (PS1)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)